# netty - Can I bootstrap a new client to connect other server in a channel handler?

Tags: java, networking, network-programming, netty

Is it possible that I could dynamic build a client client/server in the client channel handler? If it's possible, how could you achieve it? (I have tried this but failed in the build a child client when connecting using bootstrap.connect, on the other hand, I have successfully build a child server that bind with certain port, don't know why)

Is there a better way to achieve above functions, which make the client dynamic communicate with other servers/clients, not the server it firstly connected with but keep the connection alive?

Addition:
*Some of the code like this:*

```
public class FileClientHandler extends SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler {   

.....

public void getFile(final String filename, final String md5){
    // Configure the client.
    ClientBootstrap bootstrap = new ClientBootstrap(
            new NioClientSocketChannelFactory(
                    Executors.newCachedThreadPool(), Executors.newCachedThreadPool()));

    // Configure the pipeline factory. 
    bootstrap.setPipelineFactory(new ChannelPipelineFactory() {
        public ChannelPipeline getPipeline() throws Exception {
            return Channels.pipeline( new FileClientGetFileHandler(filename,md5) );
        }
    });

    // Start the connection attempt.
    ChannelFuture future = bootstrap.connect(new InetSocketAddress(Ip, Port));

    // Wait until the connection attempt succeeds or fails.
    future.awaitUninterruptibly().getChannel();

    if (!future.isSuccess()) {
        System.out.print("Connect Failure!\n");
        future.getCause().printStackTrace();
        bootstrap.releaseExternalResources();
        return;
    } 

    // Wait until the connection is closed or the connection attempt fails.
    future.getChannel().getCloseFuture().awaitUninterruptibly();

    // Shut down thread pools to exit.
    bootstrap.releaseExternalResources();
}

......
```

}

It failed at the *future.awaitUninterruptibly().getChannel();* , if delete it, still fail at the connect : *!future.isSuccess()==true*

Comment: Sorry can you be more specific. I don't understand your question..

Answer (score 0):

The proxy example actually does this, it creates a new client connection in the handler:

https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/b03b11a24860a1d636744c989dad50d223ffc6bc/src/main/java/org/jboss/netty/example/proxy/HexDumpProxyInboundHandler.java